# Create a multiple hierarchical div element structure with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use a jQuery function to add two div tags when a certain div tag with the plus symbol is clicked on. This work pretty well, however, I'm kinda stuck if I would like to add additional div elements by pressing on a div tag that has been created by the jQuery function to build up a tree structure in html.

The initial div structure:

```
<div class="left_navigation">
  <div class="row" id="header_orange">
    <div class="header_line">
      <div class="header_color" id="background_orange">
        <div class="header_prespace_lv1">
          <div class="header_given" id="orange">
            <div class="header_plus" id="orange">(+)</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The jQuery function 1:

```
$(".header_plus#orange").click(function() {

       $(".row#header_orange").after('<div class="row" id="attribute_lv1_orange"><div class="attribute_lv1_line"><div class="attribute_lv1_color" id="background_orange"></div><div class="attribute_lv1_prespace_lv1"></div><div class="attribute_lv1_given"id="orange"><input class="new_attribute_text_lv1_orange" id="orange" type="text" value="New Attribute" onclick="changeContent()"></text></div><div class="attribute_lv1_plus"id="orange"><p>+</p></div></div></div>');

       $(".blank_orange").after('<div class="row" id="testdata"><div class="testcase_data"><input class="new_data_input" type="text" value="+" onclick="changeContent()"></text></div></div>');

   });
```

Now I would like to press the plus of the  () newly created div tag and add another group of elements:

```
$(".attribute_lv1_plus#orange").click(function() {

       $(".row#attribute_lv1_orange").after('<div class="row" id="attribute_lv2_orange"><div class="attribute_lv2_line"><div class="attribute_lv2_color" id="background_orange"></div><div class="attribute_lv2_prespace_lv2"></div><div class="attribute_lv2_given"id="orange"><input class="new_attribute_text_lv2_orange" id="orange" type="text" value="New Attribute" onclick="changeContent()"></text></div><div class="attribute_lv2_plus"id="orange"><p>+</p></div></div></div>');

       $(".blank_orange").after('<div class="row" id="testdata"><div class="testcase_data"><input class="new_data_input" type="text" value="+" onclick="changeContent()"></text></div></div>');

   });
```

But it does not work, when I include the `attribute_lv1` structure then it works, but when I would like to add the element group sequentially it does not work. Is there a possible workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: You may need to inquiry about event delegation https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/ . This technique will require you to attach event listener to nearest statically created parent and specify additional `.on()` argument (in between event type and callback function wich corresponds to your dynamically created element selector

Comment: Why do you have two elements with `id="orange`?

Comment: Thank you for your fast reponse! I will look into the event delegation and try it out. I use the id="orange" for orange font color in css,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is that you are creating a click-event to an element that does not exists at the moment. creating the click-event after creating the element will do the trick:

```js
$(".header_plus#orange").click(function() {
  var id_1v1 = new Date();
  $(".row#header_orange").after('<div class="row 1v1" id="' + id_1v1.getTime() +'">' +
    '<div class="attribute_lv1_line"><div class="attribute_lv1_color" id="background_orange"></div>' +
    '<div class="attribute_lv1_prespace_lv1"></div>' +
    '<div class="attribute_lv1_given orange"><input class="new_attribute_text_lv1_orange orange" type="text" value="New Attribute" onclick="changeContent()"></text></div>' +
    '<div class="attribute_lv1_plus orange" data-target="' + id_1v1.getTime() + '"><p>+</p></div></div></div>');

  $(".blank_orange").after('<div class="row"><div class="testcase_data"><input class="new_data_input" type="text" value="+" onclick="changeContent()"></text></div></div>');

  $(".attribute_lv1_plus").click(function() {
    var id_1v2 = new Date();
    $('#'+$(this).data('target')).after('<div class="row v2" id="' + id_1v2.getTime() + '">' +
      '<div class="attribute_lv2_line"><div class="attribute_lv2_color" id="background_orange"></div>' +
      '<div class="attribute_lv2_prespace_lv2"></div>' +
      '<div class="attribute_lv2_given orange"><input class="new_attribute_text_lv2_orange orange" type="text" value="New Attribute" onclick="changeContent()"></text></div>' +
      '<div class="attribute_lv2_plus orange" data-target="' + id_1v2.getTime() + '"><p>+</p></div></div></div>');

    $(".blank_orange").after('<div class="row" id="testdata"><div class="testcase_data"><input class="new_data_input" type="text" value="+" onclick="changeContent()"></text></div></div>');
    
    $(".attribute_lv2_plus").click(function() {
      var id_1v3 = new Date();
      $('#'+$(this).data('target')).after('<div class="row v3" id="' + id_1v3.getTime() + '">' +
        '<div class="attribute_lv3_line"><div class="attribute_lv2_color" id="background_orange"></div>' +
        '<div class="attribute_lv3_prespace_lv2"></div>' +
        '<div class="attribute_lv3_given orange"><input class="new_attribute_text_lv2_orange orange" type="text" value="New Attribute" onclick="changeContent()"></text></div><p></p></div></div>');

      $(".blank_orange").after('<div class="row" id="testdata"><div class="testcase_data"><input class="new_data_input" type="text" value="+" onclick="changeContent()"></text></div></div>');

    });
  });
});
```

```css
.v2 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.v3 {
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left_navigation">
  <div class="row" id="header_orange">
    <div class="header_line">
      <div class="header_color" id="background_orange">
        <div class="header_prespace_lv1">
          <div class="header_given" id="orange">
            <div class="header_plus" id="orange">(+)</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> note that you have to use unique ids. in this case i'm using `new Date()` and `getTime()` to generate unique ids.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the quick response, that's what I thoght because if I have the div element from the start then it works. Unfortunately one of the requirements is that when the page load only the parent element should exist and then I should be able to add additional elements on the same hierarchy or below. (tree view structure)

Comment: you're welcome, please mark as the right answer if i solved your issue and feel free to upvote if you like to. ;)

Comment: I wanted to upvote but I have not enough reputation: (Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.)

Comment: as you can see, i've put your second function into the first function right after creating the element. on page load there is only the parent element and you're able to add your additional elements.

Comment: updated my answer. now using unique ids and added some css to style the treeview